# Column template in kendo grid gets overwritten

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, razor-2

I have a kendo grid in cshtml view and I am trying to set a custom template for the Payments column, here is the code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.YearlyRow>

<div class="boxcenter">
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="kendo_grid">
    @(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Excel())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Account.AccountName).Title("Account Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.PlanName).Title("Plan Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Payments).Title("Payments").Template(
             @<text>
                <strong>@item.Payments.Count</strong>
             </text>
        );
    })
    .DataSource(datasource =>
        datasource.Ajax().ServerOperation(false)
    )
)
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the YearlyRow Model:

```
public class YearlyRow
    {
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public string PlanName { get; set; }
        public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
        public YearlyRow()
        {
            Payments = new List<Payment>();
        }
    }
```

The Payments column should display all the Payment records in a custom fashion not yet implemented and is just displaying the Payment Count for the moment.

**The problem is that the Count is displayed very briefly and then replaced by** "[Object object]" which seems to be returned by Payments.ToString(). How to avoid this behaviour? I just to display what I specified in the Template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Ajax binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding) so you need a [client template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-apply-conditional-logic-in-column-client-templates):

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Payments).Title("Payments")
       .ClientTemplate(@"<text><strong>@item.Payments.Count</strong></text>");
```